# how send List inside of Object serialized by intent in android - java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using a class serialized, but the list retrieve null

```
    public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private List list;
    
    public Person(String name, List list){
        this.name = name;
        this.list = list;
      }
    }
```

I send data with list filled

```
 bundle.putSerializable("person",p);
```

I retrieve data in fragment

```
 Person p= (Person)requireArguments().getSerializable("person");
```

I get name , but list is null

Comment: Try to define type of list and implements Serializable.

Comment: the list is of String

Answer (score 0):

Does your class have a constructor?

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private List list;
    
    public Person(String name, List list){
        this.name = name;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: yeah, of course